# Dynamic, async loading of JS and IE 6 memory leak

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

I've chosen for a project to implement a on-demand script loader (in this case, for an HTML5/Flash video player). I didn't want to use a library, and I didn't want to XHR/AJAX it. (A common choice for some libraries, such as current versions of jQuery - i.e., `getScript`.) I referenced a few pieces of code, including older versions of jQuery and it's `getScript` that used `document.createElement("script")` to create the DOM element that grabs the code. Looking at it, they did a few peculiar things, the biggest of which being setting to `null` the `onload` and `onreadystatechange` properties of the `script` element. They would also delete/remove the `script` element from the DOM as well.

I understand why the first thing would be necessary, to prevent IE 6's issue with reference counting and not garbage collecting the DOM element or the event handler function when it's already used. But deleting the `script` element as well... is that necessary? Will the script, and any code in it yet to execute, still run, even if the `script` element has been deleted? I'd assume it would; I've just never deleted a `script` element of any kind, whether originally a part of the document (static) or inserted on the fly (dynamic).